# Batch copy paste from txt file to doc file on mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, batch

I have a bunch of .txt files, sorted in different folders. 
I need to convert all of .txt files to .doc files.

I have Googled the issue and found that I could just change the extension to .doc. But this doesn't seem to work, as Word still wants to convert the file when i open it. And no matter which option i use to convert (Text only, Unicode text, etc.) the file doesn't convert special characters, such as –, æ, ø, å (which is common in my language :) ). 

I have tried to choose Unicode text and choose Encoding such as "Western (Mac OS Roman)" or "Western (Windows Latin 1)" but none of these convert the special characters properly.

So - I found out, that at simple copy / paste from .txt to .doc works.. but with 100's af files, this would be a tedious manual work.
My question therefore: Is there any way this can be automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd ~/Documents/folder; textutil -convert doc *.txt
```

Or if the files are in different folders:

```
find ~/Documents/folder -name \*.txt -exec textutil -convert doc {} \+
```

Comment: It may also be necessary to also specify the encoding of the text files as described in the [textutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/textutil.1.html) man page.

Comment: Wow - that did it! Thank you very much! :) Can you explain what this does different than the manual renaming?

Comment: Doc is a binary format (try `cat file.doc`) so just renaming .txt to .doc shouldn't work. @martineau I have needed `-inputencoding UTF-8` when the input was from STDIN, but this seemed to work without it at least for UTF-8 files without a BOM (even with LC_ALL=C).